# How to run another python program

Tags: python, file

I already have

```
import os
exec(os.popen("Packman Game.py").read()
```

But it doesn't do anything and doesn't give me an error message
What do I need to do?

PS:Without typing into the shell.

Comment: What do you want it to do, in detail?

Comment: Are you missing that close parentheses in your code, too?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling an external command in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [os.system](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.system).

For example :

```
import os
os.system("myOtherPythonScript.py [parameters]")
```

Comment: This is probably ok for this specific case, but generally it isn't recommended, because it forces you do use a shell to execute the command. This can be dangerous if you're accepting user input and using it as part of the command. Instead, the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module is preferred.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can also use [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html):

```
    <!-- language: python -->
    import subprocess
    result = subprocess.check_output("Packman Game.py",shell=True)
```

If you want to read the result.